# ui-grid cell changes from outside

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

i want to make changes to ui-grid cell value from outside , for eg: on page reload. I have to calculate some form textbox value on page reload and update it to ui-grid cell. on conditions like cell edit I can directly access grid cell on event and update the cell value. But how can I access from outside on reload.

```
This.studentGridApi.grid.rows[1].entity["Name"]
```

but it is not accessible from outside. I want to do something like below

```
This.studentGridApi.grid.rows[1].entity["score"] = This.subjectScore;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing your properties incorrectly. It should be like so:

```
This.studentGridApi.grid.rows[1].entity.score = This.subjectScore;
```

This can be done in a function or triggered on a page reload so long as the Grid Options and Grid API have loaded beforehand.